# Calling an existing command in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

This is how its supposed to be done according to the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html#calling-an-existing-command)

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $command = $this->getApplication()->find('demo:greet');

    $arguments = array(
        'command' => 'demo:greet',
        'name'    => 'Fabien',
        '--yell'  => true,
    );

    $greetInput = new ArrayInput($arguments);
    $returnCode = $command->run($greetInput, $output);

    // ...
}
```

What I want to do is call the command: 
"php app/console cjw:check-symlinks --vendor=Acme"

but it doesn't work, here's the code:

```
$command = $this->getApplication()->find('cjw:check-symlinks');

$arguments = array(
    '--vendor'=>'Jac',
);

$Input = new ArrayInput($arguments);
$returnCode = $command->run($Input, $output);
```

It interrupts the execution and throws the following error:

> [RuntimeException]       Not enough arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide all arguments. Command name at least:

```
$command = $this->getApplication()->find('cjw:check-symlinks');

$arguments = array(
    'command' => 'cjw:check-symlinks',
    // other arguments, depending on cjw:check-symlinks definition 
    '--vendor'=>'Jac',
);

$Input = new ArrayInput($arguments);
$returnCode = $command->run($Input, $output);
```